# SQL Server Replication - Is it possible between two different database models?

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional

Two questions about SQL Server Replication:

1) Is it possible to configure transaction replication between a database A, and a database B (which has a small subset of tables of database A)?

2) Is it possible to configure transaction replication between a database A, and a database B, when the tables and column names are different between the 2 databases?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible to do.

1)  Using filters, you can specify a subset of rows to publish.  Have a look at [Filter Published Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151775.aspx).

2)  For different source and destination schemas you'll want to either create an indexed view on the publisher which looks like the subscription object and replicate that or look into creating a custom replication stored procedure to carry out the updates, also known as a custom sync object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, only thing I could think of would be to create some sort of ETL package that is executed periodically to move things over, but that doesn't give you transaction replication.